# How to create animate*AsState list in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

There are a set of images. I want to animated change the image size I clicked, but it does not work.

```
val targetSizeList = remember {
    MutableList(list.size){0.5f}
}
val sizeList = List(list.size){
    val state by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = targetSizeList[it])
    state
}
Column {
    ...
    Row {
        ...
        Image(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(sizeList[index]).clickable { targetSizeList[index] = 1f },
              imageVector = list[index],
              contentDescription = "")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to animate.

```
    data class ImageData(
        var id: Int,
        var size: State<Float>,
        val icon: Int = R.drawable.icon,
    )

    val list = mutableStateListOf<ImageData>()

    val listTargetValues = remember {
        mutableStateListOf(.5f, .5f, .5f)
    }

    list.add(
        ImageData(
            id = 0,
            animateFloatAsState(targetValue = listTargetValues[0])
        )
    )
    list.add(
        ImageData(
            id = 1,
            animateFloatAsState(targetValue = listTargetValues[1])
        )
    )
    list.add(
        ImageData(
            id = 2,
            animateFloatAsState(targetValue = listTargetValues[2])
        )
    )
    
    Row() {
        list.forEach {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(it.size.value)
                    .clickable { listTargetValues[it.id] = 1f },
                painter = painterResource(id = it.icon),
                contentDescription = ""
            )

        }
    }
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thanks, and I found "val list = mutableStateListOf<ImageData>()" caused a error "Creating a state object during composition without using `remember`.".It's still work to use mutableListOf instead.